# Check if a component is an instance of React.ReactElement<any> in a child map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component that loops through children and wraps them in a div. I am trying to add an exclusion to that, but running into an issue where I can't check if the child is a `ReactElement` or not (`React.ReactChild` can be a string, or a number so it may not have a type).

Trying the method below I receive: "'ReactElement' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here." as well as "Property 'type' does not exist on type 'ReactChild'."

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
  {React.Children.map(children, (child: React.ReactChild) => {
        /**
         * Exclude these components from being
         * wrapped by the item wrapper.
         */
        if (child instanceof React.ReactElement<any> && child.type === Divider) {
          return child;
        }

        if (child) {
          return <div className="l-spacer__item">{React.cloneElement(child as React.ReactElement<any>)}</div>;
        }

        return null;
      })}
```

Comment: `instanceof` is a a JavaScript operator, but `React.ReactElement<any>` is a TypeScript type. You can not check TS typing at run-time, only instancing, Does it work if you just check `child.type === Divider` (you might have to cast it as any) ?

Comment: Hey there, if I don't check the type of the child I get "Property 'type' does not exist on type 'ReactChild'."

Comment: You could make sure `child` is an object first, `typeof child === 'object'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
child instanceof React.ReactElement<any>
```

is invalid because `React.ReactElement` is not a value. It is an interface. Interfaces are just types, and unlike classes, have no corresponding value. All types are erased. They have no runtime representation.

Furthermore, JavaScript's `instanceof` is used, and should be understood, as follows

```
value instanceof anotherValue
```

This confuses people coming from syntactically similar languages with similarly named operators but wherein the right hand operand is a type. In JavaScript both operands are always values.

To perform your specific check, adjust your code to something along the lines of

```
if (typeof child !== 'string' && typeof child !== 'number' && child.type === Divider) {
  return child;
}
```

This works because the type `React.ReactChild` is defined as

```
React.ReactElement | React.ReactText;
```

and `React.ReactText` is defined as

```
string | number
```

By elminating those cases, the language knows it matches the third possible union case, `React.ReactElement`, which has a `type` property.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [React.isValidElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#isvalidelement). For your case above:

```
        if (React.isValidElement(child) && child.type === Divider) {
          return child;
        }
```