# Using displayname to identify react component Typescript Declaration

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am building a composite component in React, and I want to enforce that only children components with a specific property will be displayed.

In the below example, I've created a basic component `Trigger` with the displayName of `Trigger`. I would like the component `SubMenuItem` to be able to find the `Trigger` component using the property `displayName`. The challenge is that Typescript produces the following error when I tried to check for the displayName property on the child element,`Property 'displayName' does not exist on type 'string | number | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | Iterable<ReactNode> | ReactPortal'. Property 'displayName' does not exist on type 'string'.`

Additionally, does anyone know if attaching a property to a component for the goal of uniquely identifying is an anti-pattern? If so, does it mean that React is not built for this type of composite pattern where components are able to identify which components are passed to it.

```
string | number | React.ReactElement<any, string | React.JSXElementConstructor<any>> | Iterable<React.ReactNode> | React.ReactPortal
```

```
const Trigger = () => <button>Menu Trigger</button>
Trigger.displayName = 'Trigger'

export { Trigger }
```

```
import * as NavigationMenu from '@radix-ui/react-navigation-menu'
import React, { PropsWithChildren } from 'react'

const SubMenuItem = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
  const childrenArray = React.Children.toArray(children)
  const menuTrigger = childrenArray.filter(child => {
    return child.displayName === 'Trigger'
  })
  return <NavigationMenu.Item>
    {menuTrigger}
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">route 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">route 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </NavigationMenu.Item>
}
```

**Attempt 1**
leverage the built in type for `ReactElement` interface. Instead of adding property `displayName` to `Trigger`, do `Trigger.type = 'Trigger` instead. This compiles but the element doesn't get filtered correctly.

```js
const menuTrigger = childrenArray.filter(child => {
  if (React.isValidElement(child) && child.type === 'Trigger') {
    return true
  }
})
```

**Resources referenced**

- [Check if a component is an instance of React.ReactElement<any> in a child map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63064972/check-if-a-component-is-an-instance-of-react-reactelementany-in-a-child-map)
- [how to test children for specific types using typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76238020/how-to-test-children-for-specific-types-using-typescript?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that `ReactElement.type` is of type `JSXElementConstructor<any>`. This means that we can import the Trigger component and check if `child.type` is equivalent to it.

```
import * as NavigationMenu from '@radix-ui/react-navigation-menu'
import { Trigger } from './Trigger'
import React, { PropsWithChildren } from 'react'

const SubMenuItem = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
  const childrenArray = React.Children.toArray(children)
  const menuTrigger = childrenArray.filter(child => {
    return child.displayName === Trigger
  })
  return <NavigationMenu.Item>
    {menuTrigger}
  </NavigationMenu.Item>
}
```